# Why does String method regionMatches not delegate to overload method

Tags: java, java-8

The method `boolean regionMatches(int toffset, String other, int ooffset, int len)` of `java.lang.String` [is implemented as](https://www.zgrepcode.com/java/oracle/jdk-8u181/java/lang/string.java#L-1274)

```
public boolean regionMatches(int toffset, String other, int ooffset, 
        int len) { 
    char ta[] = value; 
    int to = toffset; 
    char pa[] = other.value; 
    int po = ooffset; 
    // Note: toffset, ooffset, or len might be near -1>>>1. 
    if ((ooffset < 0) || (toffset < 0) 
            || (toffset > (long)value.length - len) 
            || (ooffset > (long)other.value.length - len)) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    while (len-- > 0) { 
        if (ta[to++] != pa[po++]) { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Since there is an overloaded method covering the same functionality, why is this method not implemented as simple delegation, like

```
public boolean regionMatches(int toffset, String other, int ooffset, int len) {
    return regionMatches(false, toffset, other, ooffset, len);
}
```

Comment: @aldr what “gibberishy pseudo code” are you talking about? The code example of the question is perfectly valid Java code, implementing a method by delegating to another.

Comment: @Holger did you look at method2? there are at least some brackets missing and there is no return value at all, so if thats a good question to you then, ...

Comment: @Holger EDIT: and I forgot I don't exactly get the headline cause regionMatches is no String method

Comment: @aldr “cause regionMatches is no String method”. [`regionMatches​(boolean ignoreCase, int toffset, String other, int ooffset, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches(boolean,int,java.lang.String,int,int))………[`regionMatches​(int toffset, String other, int ooffset, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches(int,java.lang.String,int,int)). Since Java 1.0. And as you can look up the source code of `java.lang.String`, it doesn’t matter that the 2nd picture is cropped.

Comment: @Holger well I concure with the verdict to put this on hold cause clearly, with both screenshots of which one is is cropped the horrible headline this doesnt qualify for https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @aldr Since this is not a “why is this code not working” question, there is no sense in asking for an mvce. Further, since the question is about the first method’s implementation, the actual implementation code of the second is irrelevant. While not being best quality, a reader truly trying to understand the question can understand the question.

Comment: @Holger well maybe you could, I wasn't able to understand the title

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184327/discussion-between-aldr-and-holger).

Answer (score 2):

First, this is an implementation-dependent choice, so it might be possible to encounter alternative implementation actually doing this delegation you suggest. That’s why it is important to specify, which implementation you are referring to.

In case of [Oracle’s JDK or OpenJDK](https://www.zgrepcode.com/java/oracle/jdk-8u181/java/lang/string.java#L-1273), which seems to be the Java 8 implementation you’re referring to, the decision was most likely made for performance reasons. As you can see, the implementation of `regionMatches` with `boolean ignoreCase` parameter will re-check this parameter within the loop when two characters do not match.

It might have been the starting point for implementing both operations, but turned out to be a performance bottleneck for some cases. Usually, the decision to write a special implementation instead of handling an operation more generically, is made based on profiling widespread real life applications.

The specialized `regionMatches` implementation for the case sensitive match consists of a very short straight-forward loop over the character arrays, which can have a dramatic impact on the efficiency of the HotSpot optimizer. E.g. it might compile this loop to native code comparing more than one character at a time.

Newer JDKs had to adapt the code as, since Java 9, a `byte[]` array is used instead of a `char[]` array and might contain iso-latin-1 or utf-16 encoded data, so different scenarios have to be handled. The implementors took the opportunity to introduce delegation, [though it is the other way round](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l1386):

```
public boolean regionMatches(boolean ignoreCase, int toffset,
        String other, int ooffset, int len) {
    if (!ignoreCase) {
        return regionMatches(toffset, other, ooffset, len);
    }
// specialized case insensitive comparison follows
```

So now, you get the optimized case sensitive comparison whether you invoke `regionMatches` without the `boolean` parameter or with `false`. Further, the case insensitive match operation is also optimized in that the `boolean` parameter won’t be re-checked in a loop.